# Getting functions from child components into parent components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a big component that has 3 important functions in it--Search, Filter, and Display. I want to put each function into its own component. Filter uses a function from Search, and Display uses a function from Filter. So to pass the functions via props to each component would force me to make Display a child component and Search the parent: Search --> Filter --> Display.

Search is merely a container with logic, and it doesn't make much sense to have it be the parent component. It would be ideal if I could have the structure be Display --> Filter --> Search. Although that would require me to pass the Search function up to the parent component Filter, and Filter pass its function up to the parent component Display.

My question is, what can I do to get these components in the right order, so Display becomes the parent component, yet each component still gets the functions they need from the other components?

Comment: I don't know that Display should be the parent; it seems like the obvious child in this hierarchy. And a container with logic is the perfect parent.

Comment: In terms of code & the computer reading things it works just fine that way. But for other devs who look through the code it doesn't really seem logical that almost the entire program is being rendered from the Search container. I could change its name to Render, but that's also awkward. Now the render component also randomly has a huge search function in it?

Comment: Please provide some code for reference.